# Build a vignette for an R package only 1 time

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen, vignette

I am developing a package on 2 separate computers in a repo path that are not identical. When I call `devtools::document()` and `pkgdown::build_site()`, I noticed that the entire vignette is re-rendered. The problem is that depending on the machine, the re-rendering results in errors because the paths differ in the 2 machines for the function calls. Is there a way to make vignettes "static" so that they are never re-rendered so that when I pull on another machine and start working on the package that it will inherit the vignette and not-rebuild it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is -- I do it in a few packages, and there can be many reasons (local differences you describe, wanting to save time, ensuring identical outcomes, ...)

In essence it consists of two steps, and I am describing a pdf vignette here as that is the case I cared about.

First, you render your vignette 'as usual' locally and store it in the package.  A subdirectory of `vignettes/` will do nicely.  The file is now static and will not changed because R will only work in the level of the top-level directory `vignettes/`.

Second, you add an old-school Sweave vignette of a few lines *that includes your premade pdf vignette as input*. This was first described by Mark [in this blog post](https://www.markvanderloo.eu/yaRb/2019/01/11/add-a-static-pdf-vignette-to-an-r-package/).  Also make sure your `DESCRIPTION` file is setup for a standard Sweave vignette.  With this setup, you no longer need to declare `knitr` or `RMarkdown` because your standard `R CMD ...` process no longer involves them.

You can look at my [anytime package](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) and its [`vignettes/` directory](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/tree/master/vignettes) as a working example.

Comment: :)  Glad to hear I am making somebody's day. The methods has its critics who claim that vignettes are for testing -- but as you found there can be reasons not to force a run.  If this helps you please show it by "accepting" the answer (click on tickmark) and "upvoting" it (click on the upward-facing triangle).  Thanks!